# Can't Run the Web Application Project using IntelliJ IDEA | Glassfish

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-8, glassfish

I have tried to create a web application project using IntelliJ IDEA and I am using a Glassfish 6.2.5 version as the server and JDK version is 1.8 but when I started the server it showed this error

> Application Server was not connected before run
> configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server
> at localhost:4848

**is there someone who knows about this error please help me.**

this is the log

```
C:\glassfish6\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
C:\Users\Lakshitha\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_312\bin\java.exe -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\Lakshitha\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_classpath1962225907 com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 65261 com.intellij.javaee.oss.glassfish.agent.Glassfish51Agent
Error running admin process:
Message: com/sun/enterprise/admin/remote/RemoteSuccessException has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 Stack trace: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/enterprise/admin/remote/RemoteSuccessException has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473) at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess.main(JavaeeProcess.java:30) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:64) IDEA requires application server's bundled JDK to be 5.0+, please replace JDK manually
Process finished with exit code 0
[2022-04-27 04:13:03,148] Artifact Test WAP:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment…
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/glassfish/admin/cli/AsadminMain has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
C:\glassfish6\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat stop-domain domain1
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/glassfish/admin/cli/AsadminMain has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Disconnected from server
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception does not tell you that you need Java 8 but instead that Java 8 (class version 52) is too old to run classes compiled by version 55 (i.e. Java 11).

So you need to install JDK 11.